# Aceptar cualquier carácter menos una secuencia exacta RegEx Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Mi problema se basa en conseguir que la secuencia de texto :
`<!-- Texto --> Otro Texto <!-- Otro Texto-->`

Capture solo `<!-- Texto-->` y `<!-- Otro Texto -->` de forma separada con un `regex`.

Lo he logrado con problemas como `"Texto" Otro Texto "Otro Texto"` donde solo me captura el "Texto" y "Otro Texto" con el siguiente regex :  `/\"[^\"]*\"/g`

Me doy cuenta que no se puede lograr de igual forma porque los corchetes `[]` capturan caracteres de forma separada y no una secuencia.

Si uso el siguiente regex :  `/<!--.*-->/g` capturara desde el primer `<!--` que encuentre hasta el último `-->` donde me capturaría toda la secuencia `<!-- Texto --> Otro Texto <!-- Otro Texto-->`.

Alguna sugerencia ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrías que usar una expresión regular como la siguiente:

```
/<!--([^\->]*|[^\-]*|[^\>]*|[^\-]*-([^\-]+-[^\-]*)*-[^>]+)-->/g
```

Va por tu intento de escribir `/<!--.*-->/g` sólo que hay que especificar que lo que en tu expresión regular estas buscando, es que en la parte de .* no exista la secuencia de `-->`

Explico un poco mi expresión regular:

- Como se puede ver los delimitadores **`<!--`** y **`-->`** se encuentran al principio y al final de la expresión regular, lo interesante es "validar" lo que hay en medio, eso lo hace en el siguiente punto.
- **`([^\->]*|[^\-]*|[^\>]*|[^\-]*-([^\-]+-[^\-]*)*-[^>]+)`** Aquí estoy buscando un match de `[^\->]**` o de `[^\-]*` o de `[^\>]*` o de `[^\-]*-([^\-]+-[^\-]*)*-[^>]+`, que desgloso en los siguientes tres puntos.
- **`[^\->]*`** Aquí estoy indicando que puede haber cualquier cosa que no tenga uno de los símbolos que parecen reservados como el delimitador `-->`.
- **`[^\-]*`** Aquí estoy indicando que puede haber cualquier cosa que no tenga "guion medio", lo que permite la entrada del "mayor que" dentro de los limitadores.
- **`[^\>]*`** Aquí estoy indicando que puede haber cualquier cosa que no tenga "mayor que", lo que permite la entrada del "guion medio" dentro de los limitadores.
- **`[^\-]*-([^\-]+-[^\-]*)*-[^>]+`** Aquí ya permito que puede haber una combinación de caracteres que incluyen los símbolos de "guiones medios" y "mayor que" pero en este caso no permito que haya una secuencia de dos "guiones medios" seguidos de un símbolo de "mayor que".